# PHP return arrays by reference, but also be nullable

Tags: php, arrays, return-by-reference

I am a huge fan of JavaScript's [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). I like being able to just take an array, throw it a predicate, and get the first element in that array that matches the predicate. I want that functionality in PHP in the form of a helper function.

Here is what I came up with:

```
function find(array &$arr, callable $callable)
{
    foreach ($arr as &$x) {
        if ($callable($x)) {
            return $x;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This works great. Mostly. I have trouble with getting the *exact* behavior I want regarding references. Namely, if the returned element is a complex structure (i.e., it is an object or an array), and I modify the contents of that element's structure by calling instance methods or keys on the returned value, the changes should immediately reflect in the array I pulled it from. That's JavaScript's native behavior, and I would prefer my PHP port fully emulated this.

If the array being iterated is full of objects, this works flawlessly. PHP passes references to objects by default, so this is not a problem.

My problem arises when the iterated array is full of nested sub-arrays. If I get a sub-array value returned from this function, it's passed by value and copied. If the caller modifies that copy of the found sub-array, changes are not reflected in the parent array.

Okay, so, simple fix, right? Just put the ampersand on the function definition. `&find(...)`. Easy.

But the very nature of this function is that sometimes it does not find an element that matches the predicate. So it necessarily has to return `NULL` sometimes. When combined with the return-by-reference function definition, this raises an `E_NOTICE`:

> PHP Notice:  Only variable references should be returned by reference in [stacktrace]

I can stopgap the notice by defining a null variable in the function and returning the reference to that, but that feels like a code smell. So does simply suppressing the notice. I'd prefer to not do either of those, unless I can be sufficiently convinced that it's the preferred idiom.

Evidently I am doing something incorrect, but I'm not sure what the solution should be. Am I missing a better pattern here?

EDIT: An example desired usage of this hypothetical function:

```
$main_array = [
    [ 'key' =>  10 ],
    [ /* stuff */ ],
    [ /* stuff */ ],
    // ...
];

// Raises E_NOTICE if null
$sub_array =& find(
    $main_array,
    fn($x) => $x['key'] === 10
);

if (!$sub_array) {
    // handle null case as appropriate
}

// Modify substructure of returned value
$sub_array['key'] = 20;

// Changed value should reflect in main array:
echo $main_array[0]['key'] === 20 ? 'True' : 'False';
// True
```

Comment: `this raises a notice` can you please add the notice as well? Also can you add the code where and how you are accessing the function `find()`.

Comment: I've done what you've asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Evidently I am doing something incorrect

I don't think that's evident at all: in PHP, references are links between variables; so if you want to use references, you have to use variables. As you've already found, that means that to return a `null` by reference, you need to set a variable to `null` first. In other words, you have to use a value assignment (`$foo = null`) first before you can use a reference assignment (`$bar =& $foo`).

> PHP passes references to objects by default

It's important to note that this is not the case in the same sense as `=&` reference assignment. Consider this code:

```php
$arr = [new class{}];
$foo = find($arr, fn($item) => true);
$foo->someProp = 'hello';
$foo = 42;
var_dump($arr);
```

The array `$arr` still contains the original object, but the object will now have `'hello'` in its property `$someProp`. The *variable* is not a reference, but the *object* is a mutable structure.

Change line 2 to `$foo =& find(...` and instead the array will contain the value `42`, and the object will be destructed. The *variable itself* is a reference, another name for `$arr[0]`, so `$foo = 42;` becomes equivalent to `$arr[0] = 42;`

> Am I missing a better pattern here?

Arguably the "better" pattern is simply not to use references, which are generally quite confusing to work with. If you want *mutable values*, then use objects, rather than arrays or other types.

Note that the reason JavaScript's behaviour differs is not that it uses anything similar to PHP's references by default, but because in JavaScript *arrays are themselves mutable objects*.

Translating the example above to JavaScript:

```js
arr = [new Object];
foo = arr.find((item) => true);
foo.someProp = 'hello';
foo = 42;
console.log(arr);
```

As with PHP, `arr` still contains the object, which has been mutated; `foo` was not treated as a direct reference to the array element.

Comment: Marking as answered because you pretty much answered the original question. Though, I have to ask: are you implying that PHP arrays are not mutable? They sure seem like they are. They're not like Python's tuples where you have to make a new one every time. Why am I not able to exploit that in PHP when passing the array out as a result of a function? Moreover, if an array in PHP is not mutable specifically only when returned from a function, why does it suddenly become mutable if I return it by reference? Why are references and mutability inextricably linked for arrays in PHP?

Comment: @Fawfulcopter PHP's arrays are not "mutable" in the same way as objects, they behave more like strings and integers. To see the difference, consider the code `$a = 1; $b = $a; $b++;` - the value `1` has not changed, and `$a` still holds that value; the increment calculates a new value and assigns it to `$b`. The same happens with `$a = []; $b = $a; $b[] = 42;` - the array is not _mutated_, a new array value is calculated and assigned. Note that the _implementation_ can optimises this to avoid unnecessary copying of memory (using "copy-on-write"), but _semantically_ there is no direct mutation.

Comment: @Fawfulcopter The reason it gets complex with references is that arrays in PHP are in a sense *arrays of variables*, so each element of an array can itself be made part of a reference set, e.g. with `$foo =& $arr[0];` or `$arr[0] =& $foo;`. Then any access to that array element is actually an access to the shared value, and any new copy of the array adds a reference to that reference set rather than copying the value it currently points to. That behaviour persists even when there's only one reference in the set, e.g. after `unset($foo);` **References are really confusing.**

Comment: I understand your `$a = []; $b = $a; $b[] = 42;` example as PHP creating a new in-memory clone of `$a` and giving it to `$b`. That's in the PHP documentation, and I know about that already. But what's confusing about array mutability is simple things like `$a['key'] = 'value'`. You are permitted to mutate `$a` in this way. If arrays truly are immutable under the hood, then that implies this operation calculates a brand new array with the new key added, discards the old value of `$a`, and assigns the new one. Are you claiming this is what PHP is doing? Because that would explain it all to me.

Comment: @Fawfulcopter The difference I'm trying to get across is whether you're changing the _variable_, or mutating the _value_. If you write `$a=1; $a++;` you wouldn't say you are "mutating 1 to become 2", you would say you are "changing `$a` to have value 1 instead of value 2". In the same way, `$a=[]; $a['key'] = 'value';` doesn't "mutate the empty array", it "changes `$a` to have value `['key'=>'value']` instead of `[]`". Whether that actually involves copying is an implementation detail, but _semantically_ the integer and array are behaving the same way, whereas objects behave a different way.

Comment: I already know the difference between changing variables and mutating values. I'm just looking for a direct answer to: are PHP arrays actually immutable? And you seem to be saying that they are. And I find that bewildering, because PHP's syntax for array access makes it *look* like you're mutating it. But you're telling me it's actually implicitly destroying the old array, calculating a new one, and assigning the new one in its place every time I modify it. Every other immutable language construct I've ever used doesn't behave like this. I knew PHP was whack but this is a new kind of whack...

Comment: @Fawfulcopter I think we're talking at cross purposes here; you've got some meaning of "immutable" in mind that I'm not clear about, so can't answer, and it's distracting from what I'm trying to say. All I was ever trying to explain is the difference between arrays and objects. A different description is that objects have *identity* but arrays only have *value* - you can't tell the difference between two arrays with the same contents; and if you pass an array into a function and get an array out, you can't tell if it's the same array, only if it has the same value.